# What's difference between "2>1 > /dev/null" and "2>&1 >/dev/null"?

Tags: shell

I would like to know what the `&` means in the statement:

```
2>&1 > /dev/null
```

It's redirecting standard error to standard output and then to [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket), but what's `&` in it?

Can I use it like the following?

```
2>1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: Sure, if you want to output stderr to a file named "1".

Comment: Does this help http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `&` means file descriptor<sup>1</sup>. So `2>&1` redirects standard error to whatever standard output currently points at, while `2>1` redirects standard error into a file called `1`.

Also, the redirects happen in order. So if you say `2>&1 >/dev/null`, it redirects standard error to point at what standard output currently points at (which is probably a noop), then redirects stdout to /dev/null. You probably want `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>In the context of a file redirect -- when it is the next token immediately after a `>` or `<`.  In other contexts it means something else.</sub>

Comment: So, & to tell FD. Query in my mind: then why we haven't used it in case of 2(stderr)? ow shell knows that 2(without &) is FD?

Comment: What do you mean? The syntax is fd>file or fd>&fd regardless of which numbers you are using for the "fd" slots.

Comment: kailash19 : Re-read the above post. Note that `... while 2>1 redirects stderr into a file called 1`. So try it: `printf "xxx\n" 2>1; ls -l 1`. File is there (but empty), and xxx appeared on your screen. It is legal, and useful to redirect stderr output to a file, i.e. `myCmd 2>/tmp/myCmd.stderr.out.txt`, right? but that is different than manipulating what happens to stdout '&1', and stderr '&2'. It's not a completely intuitive syntax. Because I don't have to use it very often, even an yrs>10, I still have to look this up if I want to do something new or different. Good luck to all.

Comment: What does `&2>&1` do then?

Comment: @skube: runs everything before it in the background, then runs the null command with `2>&1`, redirecting stderr to stdout (since the null command does nothing, it has no real effect).